# Parse Caching Issue IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I'm having problem while caching query. Below is the code I am using for my query. If i comment out [query whereKey:@"login" equalTo:currentUser.login] the query is caching fine.

```
//Defining the query
+(PFQuery *)queryForListingForCurrentUser{
    PFQuery *query = [Listings query];
    BOOL hasCache = [query hasCachedResult];
    NSLog(hasCache ? @"yes": @"no");
    User *currentUser = (User *)[PFUser currentUser];
    [query whereKey:@"login" equalTo:currentUser.login];
   query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
   return query;
}

//Calling the query
PFQuery *query = [Listings queryForListingForCurrentUser];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error){

}];
```

Comment: But what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Burst through the wall and asked: "And what's the actual question?", then flew away the same way...

Comment: The query is not caching when I'm using [query whereKey:@"login" equalTo:currentUser.login]

Comment: try to Add this line `query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;` before `[query whereKey:@"login" equalTo:currentUser.login];`  so it would be `query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache; [query whereKey:@"login" equalTo:currentUser.login];`

Comment: @MohitPopat Tried doing that still not caching

Comment: What does your NSLog print out? also, does your query actually return any results?

Comment: @BHendricks Yes, I am getting array count == 2 for [query whereKey:@"login" equalTo:currentUser.login] (not caching) and count == 14 without [query whereKey:@"login" equalTo:currentUser.login] (caching).